# What's a good word for 'clear mindedness' and 'an ability to see something as a whole'?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, titles

I'm looking for a title for something I'm working on, so ideally it would have to flow and be attractive.

The two best words I can think of is clarity, and panoptic. But I can't have the meanings separate between two words. I'm trying to find a word that takes the best from the meanings of both of those words (or words of a similar nature).

Something along the lines of a noun (such as a real life object/thing) rather than an adjective would probably be ideal, but either works.

Comment: In the U.S.A, this is generally called _common sense_, and it is greatly admired.

Comment: We agree on the language, @JohnLawler, but it seems to be a nostalgic view of reality. It is not as common as it once was ;-)

Comment: @ScotM: True, but that's why it's so greatly admired.

Comment: "Rare to nonexistent" is an appropriate term.

Comment: All of your commentary has been very entertaining I must say. And I have to agree with ScotM on that one.

Comment: @ScotM, are you saying that common sense was once widespread?

Comment: Maybe more of a question on my part than an actual answer, but isn't this what *pragmatism* is? The ability to see something as part of a bigger whole?

Comment: **Grokker** is apparently *not* going to make it into the dictionaries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groxis I guess the verb **grok** was enough: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok

Comment: Not in an absolute sense, @LittleEva, and my perception may be biased by age, but common sense seems less common than it used to be ;-) I grew up in an era when people were mortified by the prospect of being caught on Candid Camera. My children grew up in an age when people staged insane antics for a moment of fame on America's Funniest Home Videos. Will my children have the common sense to shield my grandchildren from reality TV?

Comment: @ScotM - or Fox "News"?

Comment: How about **acumen**... According to [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2011?redirectedFrom=acumen#eid) it means "Sharpness of wit, quickness or penetration of perception, keenness of discrimination; (now esp.) the ability to make good judgements and decisions."

Comment: Maybe someone should post a followup question on EL&U: "Is _common sense_ an oxymoron?"

Comment: Now that I think of it that way, @Sven, *common sense* is as **common** as it ever was; it just seems to hover at a lower sensibility.  I seem to remember my father and grandfather feeling the same way about my generation ;-)

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis, the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=acumen&searchmode=none) of acumen commends it highly as an answer.  The *-men* seems to a fortuitous linguistic coincidence of Latin morphology, but it still welcomes: *mental acuity.*

Comment: which one did you go for in the end?

Answer (score 12):

[lucidity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lucidity)

> n.  **the ability to see things clearly**; rationality; sanity:

Comment: This is close, but I'm not sure it's the best fit. If someone is described as "lucid", my default interpretation is that it's a description of their *state of consciousness* (e.g. as opposed to being asleep, or intoxicated, or feverish), not their *personality* or *ability* to think clearly.

Comment: @David How ironic...

Comment: @David I agree--if someone is described as being "lucid," that's my initial interpretation. However, I offered lucidity as a noun rather than an adjective and so it has different implications which are, I hope, appropriate to the original inquiry which seemed to be asking for a conceptual object rather than a qualitative description. Hope that distinguishes it!

Answer (score 9):

*[Astuteness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/astute)*:

> noun
>
> the ability to accurately assess situations or people
>   and turn this to one’s advantage:
>
> *oxforddictionaries.com*

Answer (score 9):

***Perspicacity*** is discerning and clear vision or intellect which provides deep understanding and insight. One who is **[perspicacious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspicacity)**:

> ...can offer solutions that are on the side of right and truth; is able
>   to see through things — read between the lines; has the ability to
>   understand and interpret his or her environment.

Answer (score 6):

*[Savvy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/savvy)* offers the luxury of noun or adjective usage:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   Shrewdness and practical knowledge; the ability to make
>   good judgements:
>
> adjective...
>
> 1.0 Shrewd and knowledgeable; having common sense and good judgement:
>
> 1.1 [IN COMBINATION] Well informed about or experienced in a particular domain:
>
> *ODO*

Another benefit in using *savvy* is its propensity for [combination](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20-savvy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmedia%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcomputer%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstreet%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInternet%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbusiness%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmarket%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWeb%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btechnology%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btechno%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btech%20-%20savvy%3B%2Cc0). You can add -savvy to just about any realm of activity to communicate a persons capacity to see and respond effectively:

[image]

Comment: With faint echoes of @JohnLawler, I would say that "savvy" has effectively replaced "common sense" now that nonsense has become so common.

Answer (score 2):

I would use ***perspective***. According to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/perspective?showCookiePolicy=true)

> ***Perspective***
>   noun
>
> 1) a way of regarding situations, facts, etc, and judging their relative importance
>       2) the proper or accurate point of view or the ability to see it; objectivity   ⇒ "try to get some perspective on your troubles"
>       3) the theory or art of suggesting three dimensions on a two-dimensional surface, in order to recreate the appearance and spatial relationships that objects or a scene in recession present to the eye
>       4) the appearance of objects, buildings, etc, relative to each other, as determined by their distance from the viewer, or the effects of this distance on their appearance
>       5) a view over some distance in space or time; vista; prospect
>       6) a picture showing perspective

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Holistic which Merriam-Webster Online defines as

> [Holistic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holistic) *adj.*
>
> : relating to or concerned with complete systems rather than with individual parts

Answer (score 0):

***Visionary*** covers seeing the big picture and having a clear mind; and also having vision and foresight. It is usually mentioned as a quality of leaders.

Here is an excerpt from an article about the qualities of a visionary leader:

> Their thinking is broad and systemic, **seeing the big picture**, the whole system, and “the pattern that connects.”
>
> Visionaries who are successful at manifesting their visions base their leadership on an inspirational, positive picture of the future, as well as a **clear sense of direction** as to how to get there.
>
> [visionarylead.org](http://www.visionarylead.org/articles/vislead.htm)

Here is an excerpt describing a *visionary villain* (from *[tvtropes.com](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VisionaryVillain)*):

> These are Visionary Villains, **who see "the big picture", and have a clear head** about what they want to accomplish and how to do it without juggling a Villain Ball.

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: Alas, most of those labeled "visionary" turn out to have been having hallucinations.

Comment: @ermanen See, I like this one. But I'm stuck in a tricky position having to find either a real world example (object or thing) of visionary or a noun at least. And I can't use vision as a singular either because it doesn't seem to fit right.

Comment: @ultimatefloydian: *Visionary* is both a noun and an adjective.

Comment: @ermanen True you are right. I stated that poorly. Like I said more specifically a real world object. The word itself is good, but the title I'm seeking more specifically is a product. So the word in its form as it is doesn't exactly fit the mold is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @ultimatefloydian: But you are giving human qualities in your question. It is confusing if you are looking for an object with these qualities. Are you looking for a metaphor or a personification? As an object, "crystal" comes to my mind that can refer to clear-mindedness like "crystal clear", and as it is multi-faceted, it can provide a view of all directions as "seeing as a whole".

Comment: @ermanen I'd say I'd be more leaning towards a personification more than a metaphor. Even then, some metaphors could work too. It's more about the word structure more than anything else. Like Clarity for example could be used in multiple ways and is structured like so to allow it to be used in such a way whereas compared to a word like Visionary, it can't be placed into the same instances. I'm blanking on what the term is, but usually product titles are based upon some sort of object or a characteristic of something. Apple, Energizer, Purell..which granted some are abstract non-existent words.

Answer (score 0):

Usually occurs in short situations but I think it meets your criteria.

noun : Presence of mind

the ability to make good decisions and to act quickly and calmly in a difficult situation or an emergency:
When the gunmen came into the bank, she had the presence of mind to press the alarm.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/presence-of-mind

Answer (score 0):

**sober**
serious, sensible, and solemn.
not affected by alcohol; not drunk.
muted in color.

Answer (score -1):

[panoramic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/panoramic)

> *adjective*
>
> 1. (*Of a view or picture*) with a wide view surrounding the observer; sweeping: *"on a clear day there are **panoramic** views"*
>
>    1.1. Including all aspects of a subject; wide-ranging:
>      *"his **panoramic** vision of post-World War I peace"*

Answer (score -1):

> **[coherence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coherence)**
>   2. logical interconnection; overall sense or understandability.
>
> n. late 16c., from Middle French *cohérence* (16c.), from Latin *cohaerentia*, noun of state from *cohaerentem*

<sup>Source: Dictionary Reference</sup>

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman thanks for the edit I completely missed that spelling mistake.

Comment: This describes the thing being understood, not the person doing the understanding.

Answer (score -1):

**Cognizant**

[kog-nuh-zuh nt, kon-uh-]

adjective
1.
having cognizance (Definition below); aware (usually followed by of):
He was cognizant of the difficulty.

**cognizance**
[kog-nuh-zuh ns, kon-uh-]

noun
1.
awareness, realization, or knowledge; notice; perception:
The guests took cognizance of the snide remark.
2.
Law.
judicial notice as taken by a court in dealing with a cause.
the right of taking jurisdiction, as possessed by a court.
acknowledgment; admission, as a plea admitting the fact alleged in the declaration.
3.
the range or scope of knowledge, observation, etc.:
Such understanding is beyond his cognizance.